# Javascript Algorithm to get the excel-like column name

Tags: javascript, php, excel, for-loop

Basically what I want to do is create list of characters with format like excel column name.

for example :
a,b,c,d,.....,z,aa,ab,ac,....,yz

in php you can just looping it with this code:

```
for($char = "A"; $char <= "Z"; $char++) 
{
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

but when I try it in javascript :

```
 var i3;
 var text3 = "";

for(i3 = "A"; i3 <= "Z"; i3++)
{
    text3 += i3 + ", ";
}

document.getElementById("pId").innerHTML = text3;
```

It doesn't work for me. Are there some errors in my code? Or that PHP logic doesn't work in JS? If you know how to make one please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javacript the incrementor operator will return `NaN` when called on a string value.

You can use ascii code based implementation like

```js
var i3, i4;
var text3 = "";

for (i3 = 0; i3 < 26; i3++) {
  text3 += String.fromCharCode(97 + i3) + ", ";
}
for (i3 = 0; i3 < 26; i3++) {
  for (i4 = 0; i4 < 26; i4++) {
    text3 += String.fromCharCode(97 + i3) + String.fromCharCode(97 + i4) + ", ";
  }
}


document.getElementById("pId").innerHTML = text3;
```

```html
<span id="pId"></span>
```

Comment: It only creates :
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, 


                                                                        
What I want is :
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ......., az , ba, bb, bc, ........, bz, ca, cb,.................., yz

like excel column name.

Answer (score 6):

**Short is beautiful!**

```
var nextChar = c=>c?String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)+1):'A';
var nextCol = s=>s.replace(/([^Z]?)(Z*)$/, (_,a,z)=>nextChar(a) + z.replace(/Z/g,'A'));

//test:

nextCol(''); //A
nextCol('A'); //B
nextCol('Z'); //AA
nextCol('AA'); //AB
nextCol('XYZ'); //XZA
nextCol('ZZZZ'); //AAAAA

//output: A,B,C,...,ZZ
for(var i=0, s=''; i<702; i++){
    s = nextCol(s);
    console.log(s);
}

//output: A,B,C,...,ZZZZ
for(var i=0, s=''; i<475254; i++){
    s = nextCol(s);
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a function called next, which provides the adjacent right cell.

```
function next(currentCell) {

    let regex = /[A-Z]/g;
    let numberRegex = /[0-9]/g;
    let chars = currentCell.match(regex);
    let nums = currentCell.match(numberRegex);
    let flag = true;
    let x = 1;
    while (flag) {
        if (chars[chars.length - x] === 'Z') {
            if ((chars.length - x) === 0) {
                chars[chars.length - x] = 'A';
                chars.unshift('A');
                flag = false;
            } else {
                chars[chars.length - x] = 'A';
                x++;
            }
        } else {
            chars[chars.length - x] = String.fromCharCode(chars[chars.length - x].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return chars.join("") + nums.join("");
}

next('A1') // returns 'B1'
next('ZZ90') // returns 'AAA90'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to get done with javascript

```
var i3;
var text3 = "";
var c;

   for(i3 = 65; 90 >= i3; i3++)
{
    c = String.fromCharCode(i3);
    text3 += c + ", ";
}

document.getElementById("pId").innerHTML = text3;
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to Arun's answer, it only creates list of character A-Z, but no AA,AB,...,AZ,BA,BB,....,BZ,CA,.......,YZ